# Scanner in.hasNextInt() never returns true

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

I have tried two methods. Neither works and I'm seriously wondering why.

`display(text)` simply is `System.out.println(text)`

```
public int getMove() {

    int move = -2;
    display("It's your turn, pick a row [0-6] or [-1] for a hint: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        if (in.hasNextInt()) {
            move = in.nextInt();
        }
        if (move == -1) {
            display("How much time can I use?");
            move = -3;
            do {
                if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                    move = in.nextInt();
                }
            } while (move == -3);
            in.close();
            return -1 * move;
        }
    } while (move < -1);
    in.close();
    return move;

}
```

This code does not take any input (e.g. when I enter `5` it doesn't exit the do-while loop).

when I change

```
        if (in.hasNextInt()) {
            move = in.nextInt();
        }
```

to:

```
            move = in.nextInt();
```

it throws a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does it work for you if you enter "-1" as your first entry, then enter another number after? Looks like it would

Comment: What do you think `in.close()` does?

Comment: I've just tried this in my IDE, and after changing `display` to `System.out.println`, everything appears to work fine...no Exceptions. Are you sure it's in this part of the code that you're getting the Exception?

Comment: Andy Turner: no it does nothing
Sotirios Delimanolis: close the input stream (System.in)
Gerard Ryan: pretty sure, I put a debugger line on the function that calls this one and haven't gotten anything from it since after its first call.

Comment: @Koen I tried it too, and it worked fine. Could you please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: So if it closes the input stream, can the input stream contain anything else?

Comment: Tested your code too and it seems to work fine. The only issue is if anything other than numbers is entered you're trapped where only dragons exist.

Answer (score 1):

This will skip reading anything that is not an integer

```
 if (in.hasNextInt()) {
        move = in.nextInt();
    }
```

so when you enter "abcd" it will forever stay in the buffer.

Add `in.nextLine()` at the end of loop to "skip" invalid input.

Comment: I have added this and it works when I make a test class out of it (MCVE from what I understand), but it does not return anything within my code.
Is it possible that it is conflicting with previous (closed) scanners?

Comment: it may be the case, as the `Scanner.close()` will also close its underlying readable, in this case System.in so you would not be able to read from System.in anymore.

Comment: Probably the case yes. Now all I have to figure out is when to close the scanner, but It's fairly low on my to-do list at the moment...

Comment: you use `CloseShieldInputStream` for that.
[link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html)